# How To Configure Django Authy For Two Factor Authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I have been researching Django 2 factor for the last couple days.  I've finally come to a point where I've gotten the Django Twilio phone verification to work.  Here is the code the working code...

```
from authy.api import AuthyApiClient
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import VerifyForm, TokenForm


authy_api = AuthyApiClient(settings.ACCOUNT_SECURITY_API_KEY)

def SetupView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VerifyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['phone_number'] = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            request.session['country_code'] = form.cleaned_data['country_code']
            authy_api.phones.verification_start(
                form.cleaned_data['phone_number'],
                form.cleaned_data['country_code'],
                via=form.cleaned_data['via']
            )
            return redirect('token_validation')
    else:
        form = VerifyForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/verify.html', {'form': form})


def token_validation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TokenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            verification = authy_api.phones.verification_check(
                request.session['phone_number'],
                request.session['country_code'],
                form.cleaned_data['token']
            )
            if verification.ok():
                request.session['is_verified'] = True
                return redirect('verified')
            else:
                for error_msg in verification.errors().values():
                    form.add_error(None, error_msg)
    else:
        form = TokenForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/token_validation.html', {'form': form})

def verified(request):
    if not request.session.get('is_verified'):
        return redirect('phone_verification')
    return render(request, 'registration/verified.html')
```

Using the code above along with specifying the ACCOUNT_SECURITY_API_KEY in my settings.py file is all that was required to get the code above to pass a 4 digit code to my phone.  Progress...

However, what I'm really trying to accomplish is to leverage the AUTHY app to provide the login code....I've looked at the following page...https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/quickstart/two-factor-authentication-python-django#linkcode And the code does not load on this page...does anyone have experience or know where to look so that I can get Django to work with Authy and get the code that changes every 20 seconds as opposed to the 4 digit pin example shown above?  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your issue here is that you are using the [verification API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api), which is for one time phone number verification and doesn't use the Authy app.

Instead you want the [APIs for one time passwords](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/one-time-passwords). I don't know what's wrong with the tutorial you linked to, but all the code for the app can be found here: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/account-security-quickstart-django.

Let me know if that helps at all.